# npm run does nothing

Tags: node.js, npm, cygwin

I've been working with Node.js/npm for a while, but I never used npm scripts. I was quite surprised to find that I can't get them to work at all on my Windows/Cygwin system. With a package.json like this ...

```
{
  "name": "demo",
  "scripts": {
    "env": "env",
    "hello": "echo Hello!",
    "crap": "I am complete nonsense."
  }
}
```

... all three npm run commands do nothing. `npm run crap` executes and returns immediately with an OK status (I tested with the -dd parameter); `npm run doesntexist` throws the expected error. Testing without Cygwin on the regular Windows shell made no difference.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

I finally found out myself. There is an npm setting with which you can stop all npm scripts from running. For some reason, my userconfig file ~/.npmrc contained the setting `ignore-scripts = true`. If you run into this problem, check `npm config list`.

Comment: Thank you! Why wouldn't they print a warning message when `npm run` is called directly? :(

Comment: hahah wow funnily enough I set this to false after getting spooked by npm vulnerabilities but didn't realise the consequences!

Comment: This is insane.

Comment: Oh my word why is this a thing!? I did the same as Jesse and forgot. npm please add some sort of warning for this. Like "It looks like you've disabled scripts in your .npmrc file. enable them to run local npm scripts"